# My 'Sync Preferences' are not being saved when I disconnect my Android smartphone from Banshee

Tags: banshee, sync, android

When I set up my sync preferences for my Android phone, everything works fine and my media is successfully transferred, but when I unplug the phone (after pressing the eject button and being told it is now safe to remove the device) and plug it back in again, the sync settings have been reset and I need to reselect all my playlists again. How can I set up the preferences so that they persist after the phone is disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems to have fixed itself. I have no idea what was going on, but I shut my computer down last night and started it again today and my sync preferences were intact. Strange.