# Banshee does not remember sync settings

Tags: banshee, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My 'Sync Preferences' are not being saved when I disconnect my Android smartphone from Banshee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14468/my-sync-preferences-are-not-being-saved-when-i-disconnect-my-android-smartphon)

My phone connects, mounts and will sync files properly but will not remember settings between sessions.  Why not?

Specifically I set it to sync Podcasts entire library and check "sync when first plugged in and when the libraries change."   But every time I reconnect my phone I have to reset that setting.  Is it possible to force the setting to be remembered manually perhaps?

Setup:
HTC myTouch 4g Slide (Android 2.3.4)
Ubuntu 11.10
Banshee 2.2.0

Comment: I can verify I have the same issue with Banshee 2.3.2-1 on Debian Sid, with my Android 2.3.4 HTC Wildfire S. It's quite annoying having to adjust the transcoding settings all the time. It looks like [this person was also having trouble](http://askubuntu.com/q/14468/).